# TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am getting below warning when i try to connect to my db

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
WARNING: TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum.
```

Below is my connection string

```
jdbc:sqlserver://ABC123Aamir;DatabaseName=MyDB;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;responseBuffering=full
```

I am using SQL server 2012

[image: Logs]

Comment: So upgrade your (Windows and) SQL Server so that it can [support TLS v1.2 connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe).

Comment: Which version of Windows are client and server running, and which build number of SQL Server `SELECT @@version`

Comment: What is your Java version, what is your Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver version, what is your exact SQL Server version?